# Does async and defer also work for inline JS in script tags?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, dom, deferred

I understand how `defer` and `async` attributes work when a `<script>` with an external `src` attribute is involved, but do they have the same effect for inline JavaScript?

If so, I would expect the same result for both examples.

```html
<script async >
  doStuff();
</script>
```

```html
<script>
  setTimeout(doStuff, 0);
</script>
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

For classic scripts (i.e., not `type=module` scripts) that were naturally part of the HTML document (i.e, not added to the DOM via `document.appendChild()`), both `async` and `defer` do nothing. Classic scripts always run synchronously by the parser. They are considered the "pending parsing-blocking script" towards the very bottom of [this algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#prepare-the-script-element) in the HTML Standard, which is reserved for scripts that always run immediately upon being encountered by the parser.

Module scripts are `defer` by default, even inline ones. But you can make them async and give them the usual async script semantics, by adding the `async` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

depend on where you use `async` and `defer` attribute in script tag.

`defer` say to browser to the  browser not to wait for the script. Instead, the browser will continue to process the HTML, build DOM.
In other word i say:

1. scripts with defer never block the page.
2. scripts with defer always execute when the DOM is ready (but before
   DOMContentLoaded event).
   **Note**: The defer attribute is only for external scripts.

`async` same as `defer` but it also makes the script non-blocking. But it has important differences in the behavior.

1. The browser doesn’t block on `async` scripts
2. Other scripts don’t wait for `async` scripts, and async scripts don’t
   wait for them.
3. `DOMContentLoaded` and async scripts don’t wait for each other

in other words, `async` scripts load in the `background` and run when ready. The DOM and other scripts don’t wait for them, and they don’t wait for anything.

Comment: As I said, I understand the general idea of `async` / `defer` but I'm asking about the context of having no JS file but inline JS (as described above).